# How to compare elements of one dataframe to another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, weather

I have a dataframe, called `PORResult`, of daily temperatures where rows are years and each column is a day (121 rows x 365 columns). I also have an array, called `Percentile_90`, of a threshold temperature for each day (length=365). For every day for every year in the `PORResult` dataframe I want to find out if the value for that day is higher than the value for that day in the `Percentile_90` array. The results of which I want to store in a new dataframe, called `Count` (121rows x 365 columns). To start, the `Count` dataframe is full of zeros, but if the daily value in `PORResult` is greater than the daily value in `Percentile_90`.  I want to change the daily value in Count to 1.

This is what I'm starting with:

```
for i in range(len(PORResult)):
    if PORResult.loc[i] > Percentile_90[i]:
        CountResult[i]+=1
```

But when I try this I get KeyError:0. What else can I try?

Comment: For one thing, if you're using a numeric index you want `iloc` not `loc`, which is for named indexing. For another thing, this should be able to be done with broadcasting so you don;t have to loop through the dataframe, but it would help to see a small sample of your input df and array and your expected output to make a [mcve] so we can better understand and replicate your issue. See also [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

(*Edited*:)
Depending on your data structure, I think

```py
CountResult = PORResult.gt(Percentile_90,axis=0).astype(int)
```

should do the trick. Generally, the toolset provided in `pandas` is sufficient that `for`-looping over a dataframe is unnecessary (as well as remarkably inefficient).

Comment: They state they want the output to be "121rows x 365 columns" of zeros and ones, not just a count

Comment: @G.Anderson fixed (I think)